# How to set dynamically the width of a html table column according to its text content?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, pixel, font-size

There is a `html` `table` :

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
      <td width="480px"  class="societe" ><div style="float:left;font-size:12px;padding-top:2px" ><?php echo $_SESSION[PROJET_REF] ?> - [<?php echo $_SESSION[MANUEL_REF] ?>]</div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   ...
</table>
```

The `css` "societe" is :

```
.societe{

    text-align:left;
    padding-left:23px;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;

    background: url(../include/images/societe.png) repeat-x;

    }
```

In the `column` definition : `<td width="480px"  class="societe" >` I hard-coded the column's width to 480px. It's not very good to do that ! So how to make the width dynamically to fit with the column's text width ? Here the text is `<?php echo $_SESSION[PROJET_REF] ?> - [<?php echo $_SESSION[MANUEL_REF] ?>`.

Comment: are you open to javascript jquery

Comment: add min-width: 280px; max-width: 480px; width:auto; inside .societe

Comment: But I don't know if the text's width can exceed 480 ! Why to set maxwidth so ?

Comment: What is “the column’s text width”? Do you meant the text content of a a cell when set on one line, or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the width of your `td` to change dynamically according to your text, then you shouldn't give any predefined width for the `td` element.

In **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/mSyXP/1/)** example, you can see that the first `td` has a long text, So all `td`'s within the same column will have their width set according to the longest `td` in the same column.

In the end, it boils down to the user experience. Would the user prefer `td`'s with varying widths or would the user prefer `td`'s with equal dimensions where a tool-tip would show the complete text in case it's larger in length than the width of the `td`. That, my friend, is a choice you'll have to make :)

Comment: What I prefer is the varying widths.

Comment: @pheromix, yes that was just to show you the container and the table inside it. I'm merely talking about the `td` elements and their `width`.

Answer (score 2):

[w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dimension.asp)
Use `width:auto`. I've been trying to figure it out for my own purposes (with Bootstrap 3 library) and that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

so for instance you have a div

```
<div  id="text" style="float:left;font-size:12px;padding-top:2px" ><?php echo $_SESSION[PROJET_REF] ?> - [<?php echo $_SESSION[MANUEL_REF] ?>]</div>
```

you now gone get the value of characters int and depending how many there are you add a specific with

```
if($("#text").text().length<=100)
{
   $('.societe').attr("width", "480px");
}
if($("#text").text().length<=200)
{
   $('.societe').attr("width", "580px");
}
```

and so on depending on what measures you want to use